# Convert docx file into PDF with Java

Tags: java, pdf, docx4j

I'am looking for some "stable" method to convert DOCX file from MS WORD into PDF. Since now I have used OpenOffice installed as listener but it often hangs. The problem is that we have situations when many users want to convert SXW,DOCX files into PDF at the same time. Is there some other possibility?  I tryed with examples from this site: https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-convert-docxodt-to-pdfhtml-with-java/ but the output result is not good (converted documents have errors and layout is quite modified).

here is "source" docx document:
[image]

here is document converted with docx4j with some exception text inside document. Also the text in upper right corner is missing.

[image]

this one is PDF created with OpenOffice as converter from docx to pdf. Some text is missing "upper right corner"

[image]

Is there some other option to convert docx into pdf with Java?

Comment: Not on SO; when you would be asking "to recommend a tool or library" - but why not just try to get you openoffice setup stable?

Comment: You can use JODConverter (https://code.google.com/archive/p/jodconverter/) or docx4j (http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)

Comment: JODConverter uses OpenOffice in background.. The problem is that OpenOffice sometimes hangs (crash) without any reason. I also tryed docx4j (look at my question)

Comment: That's a 4 year old article you reference there. These days, the recommended way to do it from docx4j is with Plutext's commercial PDF Converter.  You can try that online at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/

Answer (score 4):

There are lot of methods to do conversion 
One of the used method is using POI and DOCX4j

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("your Docx PAth"));
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                    .load(is);
            List sections = wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections();
            for (int i = 0; i < sections.size(); i++) {
                wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections().get(i)
                        .getPageDimensions();
            }
            Mapper fontMapper = new IdentityPlusMapper();
            PhysicalFont font = PhysicalFonts.getPhysicalFonts().get(
                    "Comic Sans MS");//set your desired font 
            fontMapper.getFontMappings().put("Algerian", font);
            wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(fontMapper);
            PdfSettings pdfSettings = new PdfSettings();
            org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.PdfConversion conversion = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion(
                    wordMLPackage);
            //To turn off logger
            List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger> list(LogManager
                    .getCurrentLoggers());
            loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
            for (Logger logger : loggers) {
                logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
            }
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Your OutPut PDF path"));
            conversion.output(out, pdfSettings);
            System.out.println("DONE!!");
```

This works perfect and even tried on multiple DOCX files.

Comment: Tryed with your method but stil get some exception:  WARN org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG .preloadImage line 76 - Batik not in class path
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/bridge/UserAgent
 at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG.preloadImage(PreloaderSVG.java:69)

Comment: import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.PdfSettings;
import org.docx4j.fonts.IdentityPlusMapper;
import org.docx4j.fonts.Mapper;
import org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFont;
import org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;

Comment: still get the same malformed PDF as in docx4j... here is: http://s5.postimg.org/ptxrxtfyf/screenshot_1540.jpg

Comment: //To turn off logger
            List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger> list(LogManager
                    .getCurrentLoggers());
            loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
            for (Logger logger : loggers) {
                logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
            }   This turns off those messages

Comment: Will try to remove log but text (upper right corner), footer etc is missing in PDF document...

Comment: Is it an originally created docx or converted . Please check

Comment: If possible provide the docx file .

Comment: It's a document created in MS WORD - Office professional 2013.. http://s5.postimg.org/63a55ovlz/screenshot_1541.jpg  If you can try here is my document: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Z9wNTXyUEeOUtFRVhZeWtnZ3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check all dependencies once and rebuild the project . IT works charm!! Thank you

Comment: Can you please send me a link with all included libraries? I have download  librarires from this site: https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-convert-docxodt-to-pdfhtml-with-java/

Comment: Also if I download latest library from docx4java I can't find Class org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.PdfConversion

Comment: The code sample in this answer uses docx4j, not POI :-)

Comment: In the most recent docx4j, the export via XSL FO is a separate library, so you'd need that jar and its dependencies.  Or use our commercial PDF Converter I recommended in my other comment :-)

Comment: HI JasonPlutext.. Have tryed your online converter but in generated PDF there is no image in the lower left corner...  http://s5.postimg.org/k5w2ko0zr/screenshot_1542.jpg   ant this is original document: http://s5.postimg.org/8utewau4n/screenshot_1543.jpg   any idea?

Comment: Would need to see the source docx.  Can you email it to me, or drag it to http://ndoc.it and paste the resulting link here?